# Getting selected item from a listbox

Tags: c#, winforms

My issue is pretty weird, I am trying to write to a string the selected item of a list, and my string is always empty.

This is my code:

```
void loader(MethodInfo[] methArr)
{
    //string abba = "";

    listBox1.Items.Clear();

    //loop
    for (int i = 0; i < methArr.Length; i++)
    {
         ab = ab.AppendLine(methArr[i].ToString());
         //abba = ab.ToString();
         listBox1.Items.Add(ab);
         ab.Clear();
    }


}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    checker();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string a = listBox1.GetItemText(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
    string b = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    string c = "dummy";
    MessageBox.Show(a + b + c);
}
```

If I use SelectedIndex it will show me the index, but otherwise I'll get just the C string

This is my full code : http://pastebin.com/i0McETZz

[image]

DEBUG - EDIT2
[image]

Comment: Try `listBox1.GetItemText(listBox1.SelectedItem);`

Comment: still not working, look over my thread

Comment: Isn't that code java? I know that C# is similar to java but is it so similar?

Comment: @Synoon no, this is C#, look at tags.

Comment: ow yeah thx String ;)

Comment: What will your program give, when you print "listBox1.SelectedItem.toString()" ?

Comment: Exactly what you see in the upper screenshot, nothing, it's null for somekind of a reason.

Comment: @ExtremeSwat no, I mean pure `listBox1.SelectedItem.toString()` without `listBox1.GetItemText` ...

Comment: same blank message box

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't add the string builder to the list, that's an object reference to an object collection. Use the `ToString()` method (as you have commented out)

See this example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                builder.Append(i);
                listBox1.Items.Add(builder);
                builder.Clear();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                builder.Append(i);
                listBox2.Items.Add(builder.ToString());
                builder.Clear();
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string a = listBox1.GetItemText(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
            string b = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            string c = listBox1.GetItemText(listBox1.SelectedItem);
            string d = listBox2.GetItemText(listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString());
            string f = listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
            string g = listBox2.GetItemText(listBox2.SelectedItem);
            MessageBox.Show("1:" + a + b + c + "\r\n2: " + d+ f + g);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like I was 2 seconds too slow LOL. +1

Answer (score 2):

If you want to retrieve the display text of the item, use the GetItemText method:

```
string text = listBox1.GetItemText(listBox1.SelectedItem);
```

Comment: if you step through your code( using breakpoints + F10), does the variables 'a' 'b' and 'c' get a value retrieved?

Comment: Have a look over my edit, seems like the "selected item is null", but I do select it, if I would not select it and press start method, I'd get an error ( exception )

Comment: You could also look at the different **Event Handlers** which maybe of  use.

Answer (score 2):

This is because of the way you are *adding* the items rather than the way you are retrieving them.

When you call `listBox1.Items.Add(ab);` you are adding the *instance* `ab` to the `listbox`. This means you have 4 references to `ab` in your listbox but `ab` is empty due to the `ab.Clear()` call. The text must be set on the value of `ab` at the time it was added to the listbox but when you retrieve the referenced item you get the *current* `ab` which is empty.

To solve this you can create a new `StringBuilder` on each iteration of your loop and remove the call to `Clear()`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < methArr.Length; i++)
{
    StringBuilder ab = new StringBuilder();    
    ab = ab.AppendLine(methArr[i].ToString());
    listBox1.Items.Add(ab);
}
```

Or use the ToString() method of the StringBuilder:

```
StringBuilder ab = new StringBuilder();                
for (int i = 0; i < methArr.Length; i++)
{

    ab = ab.AppendLine(methArr[i].ToString());
    listBox1.Items.Add(ab.ToString());
    ab.Clear();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using [a multiple-selection ListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditems(v=vs.110).aspx), so, in this way you should use `ListBox.SelectedItems`, and iterate over the received items to print them separately.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to get the selected item to ListBoxItem and then assign the content to the string you need:

```
            ListBoxItem listboxitem = (ListBoxItem) ListBox1.SelectedItem;
            string a = listboxitem.Content.ToString();
```

this is working for me, hope it helps